# How to show that a particular density is not a normal density

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, density-function

Let $\phi_{1}(x_{1},x_{2})$ and  $\phi_{2}(x_{1},x_{2})$ be two different normal density functions with zero means, unit variances and different correlation coefficients $\rho_{1}$ and $\rho_{2}$ respectively. Show that the density function $\frac{1}{2}[\phi_{1}(x_{1},x_{2})+\phi_{2}(x_{1},x_{2})]$ is not normal.

I can't see why this is. I bet the answer is extremely simple. I can see that it is a density function as it integrates to 1 (since both $\phi_{1}(x_{1},x_{2})$ and  $\phi_{2}(x_{1},x_{2})$ integrate to 1 and thus multiplying by $\frac{1}{2}$ gives back 1). So it satisfies that argument, but I can't justify why it isn't normal.

Comment: Correlation to what?

Comment: Try to plot it and you will see!

Comment: Don't you mean bivariate normal?

Comment: The suggestion by @Kjetil is excellent in that it shows what's going on.  For a mathematical proof, consider the distributions conditional on $x_1$. For $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ you know they are (univariate) Normal and you have simple formulas for their means and variances in terms of $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$; you also know that the density function in question is a mixture of those.  By choosing $|x_1|$ sufficiently large, you can demonstrate that the conditional density of the mixture is bimodal--and therefore clearly non-Normal.